# Xcode: Failed to prepare device for development

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

When I run my app in my real device (iPhone 11 Pro, OS: IOS: 15.4) in Xcode (version: 13.3), the build is succeeded, but the app does not launch in my phone and I receive this message in Xcode:
[image]

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is a short story that I've experienced during my casual work day.

I tried to pair new phone to XCode and it prompted exactly same error as yours.
At the end of the day it turned out that phone had an Apple Watch that is paired.

We simply disabled/unpaired the phone from Apple Watch and it worked out.

Maybe you can give it a try.

*Edit: Finding the XCode version that supports iOS 15.4 may also work.*

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I was targeting an older version of iOS than the one present in my device. Also, XCode was not updated and didn't support my phone's version. After updating XCode, I could change the iOS target to the latest and all worked out.